# Спросить разрешение или разрешения?

Tags: падежи

Как правильно: спросить разрешение или разрешения?

Как обосновать выбор между В.п. и Р.п. в этом случае, исходя из значений падежей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что правильно ***спросить разрешения***. Разрешение - отвлечённое существительное.

Спросить *что* и *о чем*, *что* и *чего*, *кого* и *у кого*.

**Что** (конкретный объект вопроса). Спросить фамилию. Спросить исторические даты.

**О чем** (обратиться с вопросом о содержании в общем виде). Спросить о событиях последней недели. Спросить о здоровье.

**Что** (попросить что-л., обратиться с какой-л. просьбой; при сочетании с существительными конкретными). Спросить свою книгу. Расплачиваясь со старушкой, Гагин спросил еще кружку пива (Тургенев).

***Чего (при сочетании с существительными отвлеченными). Спросить совета. Спросить разрешения.***

**Кого** и **у кого** (обратиться с вопросом). Спросить прохожего (у прохожего) адрес ближайшего почтового отделения.

**Чего** (в разговорной речи и просторечии название конкретного предмета, если указывается объект временного пользования). Потом лесничий воротился в переднюю, снял с себя всю мокрую амуницию... и спросил у людей веничка... (Гоголь). См. дать. [Розенталь](http://www.interword.se/Syntax/Lektionsmaterial/Rozenthal_Rektion.pdf)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1) А вот в этом предложении правильный падеж: "Разрешение на съемку  в публичном месте надо спрашивать в любом случае. Желательно в письменном виде".  2) И почему всё-таки  для отвлеченных сущ.  мы  используем Р.п., а для конкретных - В.п.?

Comment: Да, в 1) падеж правильный. Зависимое слово "на съёмку" в этом предложении требует единственного числа, слово "разрешение" становится более конкретным (документ).

Comment: Видимо, состояние, качество и т.д., которое обозначено  отвлечённым существительным,  нельзя никаким действием охватить целиком, полностью, а конкретное чаще всего можно. Отсюда такое предпочтение падежей.

Comment: А интересно, а в чем разница: дал совет  - попросил совета?

Comment: Дать что и чего . 1 . что (полный охват предмета действием). Дать книгу. Дать ключ от двери. 2. чего (частичный охват предмета действием). Дать денег на дорогу. Дать хлеба. В разговорно-просторечной и диалектной речи могут употребляться в
форме род. падежа также существительные со значением конкретного предмета, если указывается объект временного пользования, например: дай ножичка. Дай шаечки, когда вымоешься (Помяловский). Дайте, маменька, платочка пот обтереть (А. Н. Островский).

Comment: Попросить что, чего и о чем. 1 . что (обычно с существительными конкретными).
Попросить свою тетрадь обратно. Попросить на время эти книги. 2. чего и о чем (обычно с существительными отвлеченными).Попросить внимания. Попросить пощады.Попросить о помощи. см. также попросить.

Comment: Дать - более свободный глагол, способный сочетаться с существительными Р.п. и В.п. одинаково легко. Дать ответ, совет, разрешение, книгу... А глагол попросить у'же в употреблении, он более связан, судя по замечаниям в скобках из статей справочника Розенталя.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина, за ответы. Мне кажется, что дать совет - это дать КОНКРЕТНУЮ информацию (уже оформленную как предмет), а просить совета  - это просить о действии, о создании этой информации, когда предмет еще не существует, границы его не обозначены, поэтому его и нельзя полностью охватить действием . (Но это мои собственные ощущения и представления по этой теме).